# After changed url from http to https, it says "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: themes, urls, https

I changed url from http to https from WP Settings. After refreshing I can't access wp-login page. It says "site can't be reached"

My website link is :

```
https://jhonnathans.atwebpages.com/
```

Same question but i'm using awardspace.

Comment: You don't seem to have an SSL certificate installed. You have to do that first.

Comment: The answer by @hk89 is correct. Two other things I'd be careful of, after changing my own sites from http to https is check how plugins have written links into your database. If you get an error message about your site being mixed content, a plugin may have written http://.... to the db rather than a relative link. Also, redirect (through apache or nginx) http to https so that visitors will be redirected appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already made any of the changes above, you're not able to log into your dashboard. You can instead use phpMyAdmin to update the HOME and SITE URLs.

> Follow This Steps :

1.Open phpMyAdmin.
2.Click your database in the left pane. Several tables appear below it. Click on your wp_options table.

[image]

3.Locate the 'siteurl' and 'home' rows. Click the pencil icon next to each to edit.
[image]

4.Click the pencil icon next to each to edit

5.Alter the URL by typing in a new one

Your old url like https to http
6.Click the Go button to save the settings. Do this for both the 'siteurl' and 'home' options.

You should now be able to log into your site at http://yourdomain.com/wp-login.php.

You can change WordPress url like a http To https refer below link
[Link 1](https://websitesetup.org/http-to-https-wordpress/) , [Link 2](https://blog.sucuri.net/2019/03/how-to-add-ssl-move-wordpress-from-http-to-https.html) , [Link 3](https://managewp.com/blog/wordpress-ssl-settings-and-how-to-resolve-mixed-content-warnings)